# Konzert - auf oder in?

Tags: preposition

Es gibt aus meiner Sicht zwei Formulierungen, die einen anstehenden Konzertbesuch ausdrücken.

Bei klassischen Konzerten:

> Wir gehen in das Neujahrskonzert der Wiener Philharmoniker!

Bei "Rock"-Konzerten:

> Wir gehen auf das U2-Konzert.

Dies sind aus meiner Sicht die beiden gängigen Formulierungen. Woher jedoch stammt die Unterscheidung von "in ein Konzert" gehen oder "auf ein Konzert" gehen?

Comment: Wie wäre es noch mit "zu"?

Comment: Wie meistens: Wenn ein Dach drüber ist, geht "in". Sonst eher nicht.

Comment: Mal sehen, ob Du Antworten bekommst, die nicht rein spekulativ sind. Ich bezweifle es.

Comment: @Carsten Das mag sein - aber es kann ja durchaus auch sein, dass jemand eine genaue Begründung kennt.

Comment: @TeXnician Ja, möglich. Ich würde beispielsweise *zum/auf* das Weihnachtskonzert der Schule meiner Frau gehen, aber nicht *in das ...*. Auch wenn es "indoor" ist.

Comment: Wer sagt, dass es dafür überhaupt eine Regel gibt? Wenn man sich bspw. die Präpositionen im Italienischen anschaut, verliert man den Glauben daran, dass die Verwendung von Präpositionen irgendwelchen Faustregeln gehorcht.

Answer (score 3):

Das hängt -imho- mit der unterschiedlichen Lokation bzw. dem Zusammenhang zusammen:

Ein Philharmonieorchester spielt typischerweise in einem Konzerthaus / einem Opernhaus o.ä.

Deshalb werden solche Ereignisse meist mit dem Haus assoziiert in dem sie stattfinden, also "in".

Konzerte von Bands finden häufig im Freien statt. Die Assoziation ist hier auch eher das Event als der Ort. Man geht "auf" ein Event, nicht "in" eines...

Comment: Wofür auch spricht, dass man ja ausschließlich "auf ein Festival" geht und niemals "in ein Festival" — selbst wenn das Festival eine Indoorveranstaltung wäre.

Comment: Dagegen spricht, dass man beim Fußball "ins Stadion" geht. Bei einem Rockkonzert, das in demselben Stadion stattfindet, würde man aber "aufs Konzert" gehen, nicht "ins Konzert".

Answer (score 2):

Die [Antwort](http://www.deutsch-als-fremdsprache.de/austausch/forum/read.php?4,50887,50905,quote=1) von Franziska ist bemerkenswert hier;

> Ich würde sagen, jemand geht in ein Konzert, wenn es sich um ein
>   traditionelles Konzert mit Orchester/Chor und Sitzgelegenheiten in
>   einem geschlossenen Raum handelt. Geht jemand allerdings zu einem
>   Open-Air-Rockkonzert, höre ich eigentlich meistens "Ich gehe auf ein
>   Konzert" oder "Ich war auf einem Konzert der Gruppe XY". Da sehe ich
>   also schon einen Bedeutungsunterschied.

und die [Antwort](http://www.musikforum.de/showthread.php?10063-Unterschied-auf-in-ein-Konzert-gehen) von RSK ist auch gut;

> Früher fanden (klassische-) Konzerte in aller Regel in geschlossenen
>   Räumen / Konzert-häusern statt, deshalb ging und geht man auch
>   heutzutage, wenn´s um Vergleichbares geht : in ein Konzert (-haus).
>   Die Redewendung : auf ein Konzert gehen – kommt wahrscheinlich von:
>   auf eine Party gehen – der Party-Aspekt bei modernen (Pop-, etc.)
>   Konzerten ist ja nicht von der Hand zu weisen und stellt wohl auch den
>   entscheidenden Unterschied zu den (klassischen) Konzerten dar, bei
>   denen dieser in aller Regel eher kaum bis gar keine Rolle spielte.
>   Kurz gesagt: geht man in ein Konzert, ist man in aller erster Linie
>   der passive Zuhörer, dessen vornehmlichste Pflicht es ist andächtig
>   die Klappe zu halten und an den dafür vorgesehenen Stellen zu
>   klatschen ... geht man dagegen auf ein Konzert, befindet man sich eher
>   auf ner Party mit Konzert, wo man nicht nur brav zuhören und
>   applaudieren, sondern auch Tanzen, Quatschen, Saufen, etc. darf bzw.
>   soll.

Answer (score 1):

Die von den Mitantwortern bemühte Begründung mit dem Gebäude halten m. E. einer Analyse nicht stand, wenn man weitere Beispiele von Veranstaltungen heranzieht:

Man geht, wie bereits festgestellt, *auf* eine Party/Feier, *auf* eine Veranstaltung, auf die Kirchweih, aber auch *auf* einen Kurs, auf eine Fortbildung.

Interessant finde ich die *in*-Wendungen:

- In ein Seminar, eine Vorlesung (da springt auch kein anderer Grad von Mitwirkung ins Auge im Vergleich zum Kurs), in den Unterricht
- In die Messe/den Gottesdienst
- In die Oper
- In das Stadion (zählt das dann doch als Gebäude?)

Meine erste Hypothese, der quasi abgeschlossene Teilnehmerkreis würde zu *in* qualifizieren, ist mit dem Stadion leider auch hinfällig und Anhänger einer Rockgruppe, die ein Konzert besuchen, haben auch keinen anderen Grad von Gemeinsamkeit oder Mitbeteiligung als die einer Fußballmannschaft.

Die letzte Erklärungsmöglichkeit, die ich sehe, wäre strengere Formalisierung, also der durch Konzertprogramm/Lehrplan/Liturgie vorgegebene Ablauf.